# Power BI Function.InvokeAfter() every 100th query

Tags: powerbi, powerquery

I have a column of 12.000 VAT numbers, and I add a custom Column with code to get data from web API. I want it to pause for 1 second after every 100th row. how do i manage this?

current code:

```
    Function.InvokeAfter(()=>
Json.Document(
Web.Contents("https://data.brreg.no/enhetsregisteret/api/enheter/"&
Number.ToText([Kunde ID]), [Headers=[Accept="application/json"]]))
,#duration(0,0,0,1))
```

Answer (score 0):

See this

https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Desktop/Query-to-Scrap-URLs-with-a-pause-every-xx-URLs/td-p/352809

which basically involves a wait function you call every 100 times before hitting the API

```
let Wait = (seconds as number, action as function) =>
        if (List.Count(List.Generate(() => DateTimeZone.LocalNow() + #duration(0,0,0,seconds), (x) => DateTimeZone.LocalNow() < x, (x) => x)) = 0)
        then null else action()
in  Wait
```